# Passing a List<string> to an MVC Web API method using the browser bar

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an MVC Web API Get method that accepts a `List<string>` as a parameter. I'm trying to access this method using simply the browser bar. How is this done? Using `../APIName?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2&...` passes a single parameter between two ampersands as opposed to a list.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

1. Make sure your parameter of your action method is marked as [FromUri].  By default the value is expected to be passed from the body of the request since it is a complex type.

   ```
   public List<string> Get([FromUri] List<string> parameter)
   {...}
   ```
2. The query string parameter should be of this format `.../APIName?parameter[]=value1&parameter[]=value2&...`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it did help. The square brackets "[]" were unnecessary for me.

Comment: This isn't working for me. It works with the first 'parameter' call (with or without square brackets), but as soon as I add the second I just get a 500 message back from the server with no additional info, and no breakpoint hit in VS

Comment: @ChrisSurfleet - too late to reply but are you sure you added List<string> and not just string as the parameter type.