# Passing generic List<int> to WebApi method through the browser bar

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, restful-url

Sorry if you think this is a duplicate to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736680/passing-a-liststring-to-an-mvc-web-api-method-using-the-browser-bar) but it didn't resolve my issue.

I have a WebApi method like:

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET")]
[ActionName("Search")]
public EmpResults GetSearchResults([FromUri] string country, [FromUri] List<int> depts)
{
    EmpResults emps = m_controller.Search(country, depts);
    return emps;
}
```

and the routing table looks like:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapHttpRoute("IMO Route",
            "employees/search/{country}/{depts}",
            new
            {
                controller = "Employee",
                action = "Search"
            });
}
```

I am not sure how can I test this WebApi through simple browser bar?

I have tried the this with some success, it returns the list of employees for department 10:

```
http://localhost/WebApi.Employee/employee/search/brazil/10?connString=Provider...
```

but I was not able to find a way to pass a list of depts like 10, 20, 40. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to remove the `{depts}` in your route and pass `depts` in the query string parameter instead:

URL:

`http://localhost/WebApi.Employee/employee/search/brazil?depts[]=10&depts[]=11&depts[]=12&connString=Provider...`

Route:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapHttpRoute("IMO Route",
            "employees/search/{country}",
            new
            {
                controller = "Employee",
                action = "Search"
            });
}
```

Comment: I did try this but my bad, I didn't update the routing to get rid of {depts}. Thanks for the solution. What are the alternatives to this, if the list is too big, say 20-30 items or more. Should I go for POST?

Comment: yea, for a collection that big, I would suggest you to use a POST.